# SOAP Web Service data connection need to be "refresh" every X minutes in order to retrieve external data

Tags: 2007, infopath, forms-services

I have a InfoPath 2007 form that always give me the following errors after a certain period of time.

> Some external data was not retrieved. The form will load without the requested data.
>
> The SOAP response indicates that an error occurred on the server:
>
> Server was unable to process request. ---> Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.

Whenever I hit the above error, I often need to "refresh" the SOAP Web service in the InfoPath application.

May I know if there is anyway that I can avoid this problem without having to keep on "refresh" the SOAP Web service data connection?

Comment: Just in case anyone ask - the server is SharePoint Server 2007 and what I mean by refresh is to modify the data connection and click next and next until the finish button.

Comment: No, you can't automatically refresh the data connection. Refreshing the connection isn't even your problem - there's most likely a problem with your web service or authentication/permission. You'll need to provide further information (site architecture/hierachy, errors, logs etc.) so that anyone can help you

Comment: Hi Andreas, so where can I get those further information from? (what I meant is which folder can I find those site arch, errors and logs?) Can I assume that the logs you are referring to is this folder - c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\web server extensions\12\logs?

Comment: yes, this is the SharePoint log folder, look for further information/errors in these files. with site hierachy i meant how your SP sites are set up - http://server/sites/sitecollection/subsite. Where is your form deployed? How is your form deployed (form library, content type, admin approved)? In which user context are you opening the form? Where is the web service deployed? Can you open the wsdl?

Comment: @Andreas, I wish I could answer those questions that you asked but the SharePoint Server was in charge by another group of system administrators. It is highly unlikely they will reveal any information such as the logs to us. Probably, maybe you can tell me what are the things to look out for (assuming those questions are answered) so that I can inform those system administrators to read up themselves - for your consideration.

Comment: Ah ok enterprise, i see ;-) well i would look out for all error messages that somehow relate to timeouts or permission issues (http 401 is often thrown). In SharePoint error messages are often nested.. meaning that the first error is often missleading but leads to a more predicating error the deeper you look into the system. Also searching for the name of your form might lead to something..

Comment: @Andreas, Thanks for that Info, will let the System Administrators know. In the mean time, I am creating a virtual Sharepoint so that I can get to see the error myself.